# Repeat use of article 'the'

Tags: articles

Which one is correct:

'The first two quarters of **current** financial year' Or
'The first two quarters of **the current** financial year'

Comment: Hello, Ceres! I think at first that it should say: "The first two quarters of **the current** financial year." However, it could be in a newspaper headline: "N95 mask sales grow exponentially during the first two quarters of current financial year". Please give some time to taking the [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't. Welcome to ELU, Cheers!

Comment: There is no rule in English that "the" cannot be used more than once in a sentence. In speaking I believe most people would use "the" twice. Conrado's point that a newspaper title might omit the second "the" to be more concise is a very valid point. If you're unaware, newspaper grammar is odd compared to natural speach.

Comment: Conrado's point is valid, but the given example is too unlikely.

It's almost guaranteed that would really be "… mask sales grow during first two quarters of current financial year…" with no "the" articles at all.

There is no rule that "the" cannot be used more than once but that's putting it mildly. What matters is that there are rules requiring "the" to be used in many phrases, including anything like the example here.

Please remember always, media headlines are like lists and postal addresses: exempt from most rules of language.